# Why With Truffle, token is not verified in bsc test network?

Tags: truffle, tokens

[image]

As seen on the screen, I did the build process, but the verification process fails. I got the API key, I entered but it is not working Where am I making a mistake?

address: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xDd24215EEE88bae02A6d241834eC59284942236A

Comment: not sure that truffle-plugin-verify works on BSC, but you can verify it manually here:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/verifyContract?a=0xDd24215EEE88bae02A6d241834eC59284942236A

Comment: could you share the configuration of `testnet` (which you're passing as the arg to `--network`?